# Android: Check for upcoming turns on Google Navigation using a background service

Tags: android, gps

Is it possible to check for upcoming turns on Google Navigation using a background service or intent? My goals is to alert a different Android app of any upcoming turns.

Comment: I doubt it, but I don't know.  This seems like a security issue, so they wouldn't have built in that feature...

Comment: I can see how it may be a security issue, but the Steps array listed in the Google directions API might make my plan possible. Thoughts? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Steps

Answer (score 0):

Google Navigation means you will send the source and destination locations to the Google maps server and gets the latitude and longitudes of the path, also you will get the turn by turn directions with latitude and longitude. So you have to calculate the distance between current position and upcoming turn position, if the distance is less than a threshold value you can do anything you required.

I hope it may help you. if you have any doubts fell free to ask me.

Comment: The logic in your answer I understand. My question though is this technically possible? Looking at the google directions API [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Steps), it looks like I'd be able to accomplish my task. Does that seem to be the case to you?

Comment: Thanks Yugandhar! I reviewed your answer and the Google Directions API and I'm pretty sure I've figured it out!

Comment: You are welcome. If you think my answer is useful to get solution please vote it or mark it. Its how stackoverflow works. Why I am telling this to you because, you may don't know this as a new member.